# GLEW error (1): Missing GL version (GLFW)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm trying to use OpenGL with GLEW and GLFW. However, it appears that I cannot call `glewInit()` successfully and I get the following error message: `GLEW error (1): Missing GL version`. Similar questions at Stackoverflow haven't solved my problem.
When building my project, I am including the `glew.c` file and the directory where `glew.h` is.

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Testing", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = true;
    GLenum glewErr = glewInit();
    if (glewErr != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "GLEW error (" << glewErr << "): " << glewGetErrorString(glewErr) << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Next, I paint some stuff using OpenGL ...
}
```

Everything looks ok in the code. Furthermore, for some reason, if I use GLAD instead of GLEW, my code works just fine.

- System: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
- OGL version: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.108
- OGL vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
- Renderer: GeForce 820M/PCIe/SSE2
- GLSL version: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler

UPDATE:
Diving deep into `glew.c` code I found where the error pops up, though I can't still understand why. Here it is the piece of code

```cc
static GLenum GLEWAPIENTRY glewContextInit ()
{
  PFNGLGETSTRINGPROC getString;
  const GLubyte* s;
  GLuint dot;

  #ifdef _WIN32
  getString = glGetString;      // Not executed, I'm on Ubuntu
  #else
  getString = (PFNGLGETSTRINGPROC) glewGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)"glGetString");
  if (!getString)
    return GLEW_ERROR_NO_GL_VERSION;
  #endif

  /* query opengl version */
  s = getString(GL_VERSION);     // <<< ERROR: s gets a null pointer
  dot = _glewStrCLen(s, '.');
  if (dot == 0)
    return GLEW_ERROR_NO_GL_VERSION;   // <<< Function escapes here

// ... more statement down here
}
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but maybe you should update your GLEW version, the use of `glewExperimental` is an evil, and broken, hack which was mostly was used to work around GLEW's incompatibility with core profile contexts in GLEW 1.x., but which should never be used tbh.

Comment: I am using GLEW 2.1.0, which is the latest release (7/31/17) according to http://glew.sourceforge.net/ . On the other hand, I think it's not possible to use core profile mode without `glewExperimental`, so I have no option.

Comment: "n the other hand, I think it's not possible to use core profile mode without glewExperimental, so I have no option" That's not true.  GLEW 2.x works without that broken hack. But what's the issue in your case is not clear. One guess: you still include `<GL/glew.h>` which might use the system's version of `glew.h`, not the one you're providing, so it could be incompatible to the `glew.c` you have ibn your project.

Comment: I would recommend you to switch to GLAD. The interface is a bit more nice to work with, and for practical reasons there is no difference in your code, except for that one place where you include the GLEW/GLAD headers.

Comment: @derhass, that was a good observation, so I tried to explicitly use my version of `glew.h`, but the `missing GL version` issue remains. @ワイきんぐ, I have switched to GLAD because it is working, but I wanted to know why GLEW is not working.

Comment: "but I wanted to know why GLEW is not working" beats me, but you still can step through it in a debugger

Comment: @derhass,  you see, I want to know why GLEW is not working because I have always been using GLEW, I prefer to use GLEW, I think it's easier to install, and I don't like certain things about GLAD, among other reasons. However, as I couldn't solve this issue, I was forced to switch to GLAD.

Comment: Ok, I entered `glew.c` and found out that a call to `getString(GL_VERSION)` fails (I don't know why) and causes `glew` to output an error. I updated my post with this info